# How do put your your executables inside a bin/Debug directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using a Visual Studio 2008, C++, on a 64 bit windows machine and I am building my application as 64bit. I am little confused by the executables I get:

1) Why does my executable go into .../ProjectName/x64/Debug/program.exe folder, why does a bin/Debug/ folder not get created. e.g. what do I have to do differently to put my executables inside a bin/Debug or bin/Release folder.

2) when I run my program I get an error saying that a .dll file couldn't be found. So my question is where is the program looking for the .dll and if it it in the /Debug folder (which gets generated when the program is run), then how can I provide the .dll before running the program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Because you choose the build configuration as x64

2) You could add the dll as references in your project and set its property to copy to output folder.

Comment: 1) exactly where in visual studio under: solution=>Properties=>... do I pick the build configuration?